# Symfony2 ACL access to objects and classes

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I just started with Symfony2 ACL and I can not access the objects with the assigned user. Let me explain:

I assign permissions to a particular user of some objects. I do it on load data fixtures:

```
    // creating the ACL
    $aclProvider = $this->container->get('security.acl.provider');
    $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($order); //entity

    try {
        $acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);
    } catch (\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\Exception $e) {
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
    }

    // retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
    $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

    // grant owner access
    $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
    $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

I also want to assign permissions to all objects of a class to the role ADMIN and I do it with a command:

```
    $output->writeln('<info>Adding Order OWNER ACE to role ROLE_ADMIN</info>');

    $aclProvider = $this->getContainer()->get('security.acl.provider');
    $objectIdentity = new ObjectIdentity('class', 'VendorName\XXXBundle\Entity\Order');

    try {
        $acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);
    } catch (\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\Exception $e) {
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
    }

    $em = $entityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $role = $em->getRepository('VendorNameXXXBundle:Role')->findOneByRole('ROLE_ADMIN');

    $securityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity($role->getRole());
    $acl->insertClassAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
    $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

I can not get Symfony2 detects these permissions. I connect with the two users and when I do from Twig:

```
    {% if is_granted('VIEW', entity) %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12">Authorized!</td>
    </tr>
    {% else %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12">You are not authorized</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
```

I always get: "You are not authorized".

Also tried from controller but with the same result:

```
    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');

    if (false === $securityContext->isGranted('EDIT', $entity))
    {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
    }

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Order entity.');
    }
```

Comment: I really recommend that you look at the VoterInterface, http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15994931191/symfony2-security-voters , it would avoid tu duplicate data, and would not be a pain to keep in sync with the model.

Comment: I understand ACL. Do not understand why it does not work. I have given permissions to the user fine. If we focus only on the user who has OWNER permissions on some objects not understand why the function isGranted returns FALSE...

Comment: log searching I found this:
No ACL found for the object identity. Voting to deny access. [] []

Comment: Did you try `is_granted('OWNER', entity)` ?

Comment: I've fixed it! See the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260048/symfony2-classace-and-objectace