# Symfony2: ClassACE and ObjectACE

Tags: php, symfony, acl

The ACL class have permissions on all objects of that class? 
Or only have permission on itself and not on the objects? 
Let me explain on Symfony2:

I have an Entity Order and 5 created Orders. If I give owner permission to the class Order I have grants to edit all the objects?

```
$objectIdentity = new ObjectIdentity('class', 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Order');
$securityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity($role->getRole());
$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
$acl->insertClassAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

**EDIT**
Actually I have 2 problems:

***FIRST PROBLEM:***
The problem I have is when I use RoleSecurityIdentity. It don't works for me. If I use UserSecurityIdentity works perfectly for every object. 
This example works fine:

```
    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($salesOrder);
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
        $securityIdentity = new UserSecurityIdentity(
          'admin', 
          'Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\User');
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
        $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
    }
```

User Admin have OWNER grants !

this example don't work:

```
    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($salesOrder);
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
        $securityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity('ROLE_ADMIN');
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
        $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
    }
```

Users with ROLE_ADMIN don't have grants to objects!

***SECOND PROBLEM:***
If I apply OWNER grants to the class Order i don't have grants to access to the entities: Let me explain:

```
    $objectIdentity = new ObjectIdentity('class', 'Neventum\PaymentBundle\Entity\SalesOrder');
    $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
    $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($admin);
    $acl->insertClassAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
    $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

I need the admin user always has access to all objects of the Order entity.

Comment: For the first problem: are your Roles coming from the database (E.g: you have a Role entity different from Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role)?

Comment: Yes! My roles coming from Database. I have entity class Role implements RoleInterface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed!

The problem was on the getRoles method on User Entity.

Before it was like this:

```
function getRoles() {
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

I've changed to:

```
function getRoles()
{
    $roles = array();
    foreach($this->userRoles as $userRole) {
        $roles[] = $userRole->getRole();
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

If anyone knows why I would appreciate